# Hive PARTITIONED BY, list index out of range error?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue

I am running Hive and Hue on Cloudera.
I have the following text file uploaded to hdfs. And I'm trying to create an external table in hive partitioned by id. For whatever reason, it's not working.

/user/test2/test.csv

```
id,name,age
1,sam,10
2,john,5
1,rick,4
```

Hive:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
    name STRING,
    age  INT
)
COMMENT 'This is the test database'
PARTITIONED BY (id INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/user/test2/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count" = "1");
```

On Hue, hive editor, when I tried to look at sample data, it says `list index out of range`. Not sure what this is. The external table will work correctly if I remove the partitioned by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally solved my problem. Below is my solution.

I am using Cloudera vm - 5.4.2, when I started Hue, the Hive setting in Hue is pointing to HiveServer2; But I created the tables using Hive CLI. So basically the table only exists in HiveServer1.

Solution:
Instead of using Hive CLI, create table in beeline, everything in Hue should work then.

Answer (score 0):

Your data located on '/user/test2/test.csv' is structured on three columns, but your schema defined for the table 'testDB' contains two columns, it is normal that you have this error.
You have to update your script, by adding the id column:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
    id INT,
    name STRING,
    age  INT
)
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is not why I am getting the error. If i include id in the schema, I won't be able to partition it by id.

Comment: The creation script for the table have to define all columns for you data. Adding the id column won't impact the partitioning on the id column.

Comment: `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
    id INT,
    name STRING,
    age  INT
)
COMMENT 'This is the test database'
PARTITIONED BY (id INT)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LOCATION '/user/test2/'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count" = "1");` if you do this, hive will give you an error `Column repeated in partitioning columns`. Or am I not understanding you?!

Comment: You have to name the id differently when you do the "PARTITIONED BY".

Comment: Try something like this: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB ( id INT, name STRING, age INT ) COMMENT 'This is the test database' PARTITIONED BY (key INT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/user/test2/' TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count" = "1");

Comment: Same error `list index out of range`. I am thinking it's actually not the scripts but something in Hue/hive setting.

Comment: I guess too. If you can get more logs about your error.

Answer (score 0):

you do not have the data partitioned because you have not created it. You should follow 3 steps:

1- Mount the data pointing to the .csv file.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE TableName (id int, name string, age int) 
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/test2/';
```

2. Create the partitioned data

> ```
> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testDB (
> name STRING,
> age  INT )   
> COMMENT 'This is the test database'
> PARTITIONED BY (id INT)
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
> LOCATION '/user/other/location'   
> TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count" = "1");
> ```

3. Insert the data from your previous table to the final table.

   > insert into table testDB 
   >   partition (archive) select name, age from
   >   TableName;

Hope this help you.